# cube of any integer is of form $7k, 7k \pm 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

To prove : cube of any integer is of form $7k, 7k \pm 1$

Cube of any integer is of form $9k, 9k+1, 9k+8$ (Proved earlier).
Now question is that any integer of form $9k, 9k+1, 9k+8$  also has form $7k, 7k \pm 1$

I took $k = 2m$  and $k = 2m+1$ but reach nowhere. how do i proceed ?

Thanks

Comment: All integers are of the form $7k+i$ for $i\in \lbrace 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 \rbrace$.

Comment: this method i know. can it be done otherway

Comment: It is by using congruences, see the duplicate, either directly or by using little Fermat.

Comment: @DietrichBurde was looking for another way

Comment: Essentially there is no other way (like I said, show that $6$ is composite has essentially only one proof). The duplicate offers several ways, but they are all based on modular arithmetic - and they have to.